# Elasticsearch DSL query from an SQL statement

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch. I don't think I fully understand the concept of query and filters. In my case I just want to use filters as I don't want to use advance feature like scoring.

How would I convert the following SQL statement into elasticsearch query?

```
select * from tablename where (name="d" and time>1231312) or (name="ds" and time>21)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
{
    "filter" : {
        "or":[
            { "and" : [
                    {"range": {"time": {"gt": 1231312}}},
                {"term" : {"name":"d"}}
            ]},

            { "and" : [
                    {"range": {"time": {"gt": 21}}},
                {"term" : {"name":"ds"}}
            ]}

        ]

    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is the query DSL which is equivalent to your sql query.  The `query_string/query` filter is not cached by default that's why I have use `_cache:true` performance wise it will works good.

```
curl -XPOST http://localhost:9200/index_name/_search '{
   "filter": {
      "or": {
         "filters": [
            {
               "fquery": {
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "name": "d"
                              }
                           },
                           {
                              "range": {
                                 "time": {
                                    "gte":1231312
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "_cache": true
               }
            },
            {
               "fquery": {
                  "query": {
                     "bool": {
                        "must": [
                           {
                              "term": {
                                 "name": "ds"
                              }
                           },
                            {
                              "range": {
                                 "time": {
                                    "gte":21
                                 }
                              }
                           }
                        ]
                     }
                  },
                  "_cache": true
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}'
```